# Twitter bootstrap only looks strange on device "sm"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/W7CLF/

on `xs` devices, it looks nice, it splits to two rows, and then on > `sm` it look nice as well. Staying on one line..

But I cannot understand why it looks strange on `sm`.

As you can see I've used
`hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` on `xs`
to show different layouts on different devices and
`hidden-xs`
to show another layout on `device != xs`

Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a sketch of your results per grid maybe. So far i understand your code. It seems you will have:

xs-grid:

```
med  | 600kr
------------
home | 60
```

and sm-, md, lg grid:

```
Med        | Home | 60 | 600
```

So try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row activityItem">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"><p class="activityText">Medicinsk fotvård</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-push-4"><p class="activityText activityTextRight">600 kr</p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-2"><p class="activityText activityTextRight"><i class="fa fa-home">Home</i></p></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-2"><p class="activityText activityTextRight">60 minuter</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**notes**: 
In your code you use: `col-md-6 hidden-xs` you define nothing for the sm-grid here. This div will get 100% width on the sm grid. try `col-sm-6 hidden-xs` You also use `col-md-6 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg` only visible on the xs-grid. your `col-md-6` has no effect on this grid.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! Will have to think a while though how these pull and push works.. Not sure. But thanks!